# Image player issue with jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, setinterval, timing

I've made a jQuery player for images [Demo Link](http://jsfiddle.net/9gyu666n/3/).

It changes the screens with provided intervals and draws touches on it. Now, I want to implement pouse, play functionality.
When I click on play button to stop screen playing, I call `FlowPlaye.stop()` method:

```
FlowPlayer.prototype.stop = function() {
        $(".fp-pause").removeClass("fp-pause").addClass("fp-play");
        clearInterval(this.screenIntervalId);
        clearInterval(this.timeIntervalId);
        clearInterval(this.touchIntervalId);
        $('.fp-progress').stop();
        this.isAnimated = false;
        return false;
    }
```

And at the second time `FlowPlayer.play()`:

```
FlowPlayer.prototype.play = function() {
    var fp = this; // Obj refers to the FlowPlayer itself such as "this"
    fp.isAnimated = true;
    console.log(typeof this.screenIndex)
    console.log(this.screenIndex)

    fp.screenIndex = typeof this.screenIndex == 'number' ? this.screenIndex : 0; 
    fp.render(fp.screens[fp.screenIndex]);
    fp.initTimeline(fp.duration);

    fp.screenIntervalId = setInterval(function() {
        if (fp.screenIndex == fp.screens.length - 1) {
            console.log("the end of screens");
            clearInterval(fp.screenIntervalId)
            return;
        }
        ++fp.screenIndex;
        fp.render(fp.screens[fp.screenIndex]);
    }, fp.screens[fp.screenIndex].delay)


}
```

The problem is that when I do this, the screen playing intervals are messing (try to stop video at 20th second and restore). I need to save state of player, but I don't know how.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think using 3 different timers is making this unnecessary difficult. If you refactor it into 1 unified timer, pausing (and other playback controls) would be quite easy.

1. Separate your keyframe events into separate functions:

   ```
   function setImage(img) {...}
   function showTouch(x, y) {...}
   function hideTouch() {...}
   ```
2. On startup, convert your `screens` array to something like this:

   ```
   var keyframes = [
           { time:0,    func:setImage,  args:['http://...']},
           { time:1000, func:showTouch, args:[10, 30]},
           { time:3000, func:hideTouch, args:[]},
           ...
       ];
   ```
3. Set up a single timer for playback:

   ```
   var time = 0,
       next = 0,
       isPaused = false,
       interval;
   function timer() {
       if (isPaused) {
           return;
       }
       var nextKeyframe = keyframes[next];
       time += 100;
       if (time >= nextKeyframe.time) {
           nextKeyframe.func.apply(this, nextKeyframe.args);
           next += 1;
           if (next === keyframes.length) {
               clearInterval(interval);
           }
       }
   }
   ```
4. Now, you have an easily controllable playback:

   ```
   // play / replay - reset time and next, then start the timer
   time = 0;
   next = 0;
   interval = setInterval(timer, 100);

   // seek - just set a new time, and find the next keyframe
   time = 1500;
   for (next = 0; keyframes[next].time < time && next < keyframes.length; next++) {}

   // pause - the timer stays on, but won't do anything
   isPaused = true;

   // stop
   clearInterval(interval);
   ```

Note: The snippets are untested, may have some typos in them. I just wanted to demonstrate the process of making it cleaner / more controllable.